# .Net Core 2 Spring.Rest.Client.RestTemplate Operation is not supported on this platform. Exception

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, oauth-1.0a

I'm using Spring.Net.Social.Core to get access to web API. Authorization goes correct but when I'm trying to send GET request to server ...

```
RestOperations.GetForMessage<JsonValue>($"https://www.blablabla.com/{url}?tq={query}")
```

I have "Operation is not supported on this platform" error. StackTrace below:

```
   at System.Net.SystemWebProxy.GetProxy(Uri destination)
   at System.Net.ServicePointManager.ProxyAddressIfNecessary(Uri& address, IWebProxy proxy)
   at System.Net.ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(Uri address, IWebProxy proxy)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.get_ServicePoint()
   at Spring.Http.Client.WebClientHttpRequestFactory.CreateRequest(Uri uri, HttpMethod method)
   at Spring.Http.Client.Interceptor.InterceptingClientHttpRequestFactory.RequestCreation.Create()
   at Spring.Http.Client.Interceptor.InterceptingClientHttpRequestFactory.RequestCreation.Create()
   at Spring.Http.Client.Interceptor.InterceptingClientHttpRequestFactory.CreateRequest(Uri uri, HttpMethod method)
   at Spring.Rest.Client.RestTemplate.DoExecute[T](Uri uri, HttpMethod method, IRequestCallback requestCallback, IResponseExtractor`1 responseExtractor)
   at Spring.Rest.Client.RestTemplate.Execute[T](String url, HttpMethod method, IRequestCallback requestCallback, IResponseExtractor`1 responseExtractor, Object[] uriVariables)
   at Spring.Rest.Client.RestTemplate.GetForMessage[T](String url, Object[] uriVariables)
```

Comment: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/1061

Comment: @itdoesntwork that correct for RestSharp. Not for  Spring.Rest.Client